# Error while launching multiple instance of an e4 application in linux system of an exe

Tags: linux, swt, rcp, multiple-instances, e4

I am  creating  multiple instances of an e4 rcp application using -data @ none. By using this multiple instances are getting created in Windows 7 successfully but when I run the application in linux in the terminal by ./applicationname  it throws an error as associated workspace already in use. So how can we create multiple instances in linux? Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: The `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application` application does actually require a workspace location so I think your Windows code may not be doing what you think. What does `Platform.getInstanceLocation()` give you on Windows?

Comment: It gives the path of the exe located and executed.even i need to create multiple instance like in windows for linux system

Comment: The location should be null if `-data @none` is specified.

Comment: Platform.getInstanceLocation() gives null in Windows PC, when i specify -data @none in launching arguments

Answer (score 0):

The E4Application does require a workspace location. You can set one in the LifeCycle `@PostContextCreate` method:

```java
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate()
{
  Location instanceLoc = Platform.getInstanceLocation();

  // -data @none specified?

  if (instanceLoc == null)
    return;

  // OK if location is set

  if (instanceLoc.isSet())
    return;

  // TODO construct a workspace location

  instanceLoc.set(url of location, false);
}
```

Comment: But in this how can we dynamically change url of location to set instance loc